# Efficiently checking if arbitrary object is NaN in Python / numpy / pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My numpy arrays use `np.nan` to designate missing values. As I iterate over the data set, I need to detect such missing values and handle them in special ways.

Naively I used `numpy.isnan(val)`, which works well unless `val` isn't among the subset of types supported by `numpy.isnan()`. For example, missing data can occur in string fields, in which case I get:

```
>>> np.isnan('some_string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Other than writing an expensive wrapper that catches the exception and returns `False`, is there a way to handle this elegantly and efficiently?

Comment: `pandas` has `pandas.isnull()`: I'm not sure if that meets your needs, so some example data might be good.

Comment: @Marius: `pandas.isnull()` seems to work perfectly. The only data type I'm currently dealing with which breaks `numpy.isnan()` is string, and `pandas.isnull()` handles it well. In fact, it seems to handle well all any arbitrary object I threw at it. Were there any specific issues you were concerned about?  Otherwise, you may want to submit your comment as a full-fledged answer, since it seems like the canonical answer, at least for pandas users.

Comment: That's why `float('nan') == float('nan')` should return True!

Answer (score 224, accepted):

`pandas.isnull()` (also `pd.isna()`, in newer versions) checks for missing values in both numeric and string/object arrays. From the documentation, it checks for:

> NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays

Quick example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(['apple', np.nan, 'banana'])
pd.isnull(s)
Out[9]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

The idea of using `numpy.nan` to represent missing values is something that `pandas` introduced, which is why `pandas` has the tools to deal with it.

Datetimes too (if you use `pd.NaT` you won't need to specify the dtype)

```
In [24]: s = Series([Timestamp('20130101'),np.nan,Timestamp('20130102 9:30')],dtype='M8[ns]')

In [25]: s
Out[25]: 
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00
1                   NaT
2   2013-01-02 09:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]``

In [26]: pd.isnull(s)
Out[26]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 25):

Is your type really arbitrary?  If you know it is just going to be a int float or string you could just do

```
 if val.dtype == float and np.isnan(val):
```

assuming it is wrapped in numpy , it will always have a dtype and only float and complex can be NaN

Comment: I am dealing with many different types of data. While most columns have int* or float* data types, others could be any object, although so far the only other type I used was string.

Comment: Strings in python doesn't have `dtype`. You may have to do `type(val) == 'float'`

Comment: `type(val) == float and np.isnan(val)` - worked for me

Comment: @user1930402 I'm assuming these are numpy arrays not regular python ones.  For example: np.array(["hello"])[0].dtype works but ["hello"][0].dtype does not

Comment: @pnv type(object) returns the class, not a string

Answer (score 11):

I found this brilliant solution here, it uses the simple logic NAN!=NAN.
https://www.codespeedy.com/check-if-a-given-string-is-nan-in-python/

Using above example you can simply do the following. This should work on different type of objects as it simply utilize the fact that NAN is not equal to NAN.

```
 import numpy as np
 s = pd.Series(['apple', np.nan, 'banana'])
 s.apply(lambda x: x!=x)
 out[252]
 0    False
 1     True
 2    False
 dtype: bool
```

Comment: As of right now, [it seems that NAN is the only built-in value that is not equal to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253497/in-what-situation-is-an-object-not-equal-to-itself), but this introduces a very-hard-to-find bug if other values are added into the list that are not nan, yet don't equal themselves. For strings and numbers (including +/-`float('inf')`), I believe this should work just fine.