# Dealing with NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and I want to return a subset (new copy not reference) of this dataframe to perform some operations. However I find it unable to filter on the criteria i need.

I need these three criteria to filer :

```
1. df['A'] != NaN
2. df['B'] == 'X' | df['B'] == NaN
3. df['C'] == NaN
```

Currently i am doing this for criteria 1 but I am a little stuck with how to include criteria 2 and 3.

```
    filter_data = df.loc[(df['A'].dropna)]
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689512/efficiently-checking-if-arbitrary-object-is-nan-in-python-numpy-pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need special function for `NaN` - [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df['A'].notnull()
(df['B'] == 'X') | (df['B'].isnull())
df['C'].isnull()
```

Comment: Can't use `'NaN'` in `df.eval()`?

Comment: I think no, the best is use highly optimalized pandas fuction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `query` to find nulls or not nulls.  Nulls have the tendency not to be equal to themselves.

`df.dropna(subset=['A'])` <=> `df.query('A == A')` <=> `df[df.A.notnull()]`

---

Your three filters using `query`

1. `df.query('A == A')` or `df.dropna(subset=['A'])` or `df[df.A.notnull()]`
2. `df.query('B == "X" | B != B')` or `df.query('B == "X" or B != B')`
3. `df.query('C != C')` or `df[df.C.isnull()]`