# Total Number of Missing Attributes

Tags: python, pandas

Using python and panda: For a given data set how does one find the total number of missing attributes? I have found the number for each column, but I need to sum the columns using python to find the total. Below is the code I have currently used.

```
def num_missing(x):
    return sum(x.isnull())
print("Missing Values per Column:")
print(data_file1.apply(num_missing))
```

Comment: `data_file1.isnull().sum(0)` <- per column; `data_file1.isnull().sum().sum()` <-- df wide NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: call `.sum()` twice, where the second call finds the sum of the intermediate Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,5)))
df.iloc[2:4, 1:3] = np.nan
df.isnull().sum().sum()
# 4
```

Option 2: use underlying NumPy array.

```
np.isnan(df.values).sum()
# 4
```

Option 2 should be significantly faster (8.5 us vs. 249 us on this sample data).

As noted by @root and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689512/efficiently-checking-if-arbitrary-object-is-nan-in-python-numpy-pandas), `np.isnan()` works only on numeric data, not `object` dtypes.  `pandas.DataFrame.isnull()` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: note that `np.isnan` will only work on numeric data, e.g. `np.isnan(pd.Series(['foo', np.nan]).values)` will raise.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `df` -

```
df

     A  B    C
0  1.0  4  NaN
1  2.0  5  1.0
2  NaN  6  6.0
3  NaN  7  3.0
```

---

1. Column-wise NaN count -

   ```
   df.isnull().sum(0)

   A    2
   B    0
   C    1
   dtype: int64
   ```
2. Row-wise NaN count -

   ```
   df.isnull().sum(1)

   0    1
   1    0
   2    1
   3    1
   dtype: int64
   ```
3. `df`-wide NaN count -

   ```
   df.isnull().values.sum()
   3
   ```