# In what situation is an object not equal to itself?

Tags: python

I found the following lines in the `json/encoder.py` module:

```
if o != o:
   text = 'NaN'
```

In what situation is an object not equal to itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen in the case of  floating point numbers that adhere to IEEE 754 standard. See [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

By definition, a value of NaN ("not a number") is unequal to itself.

Answer (score 7):

The question seems to be about NaN, but it's worth mentioning that you can define the comparison method [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) in a custom class.

For example you could make it always false:

```
class NotEqual:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

n = NotEqual()
print(n == n)  # -> False
```