# What does x[x!=x] mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I don't understand [this line](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/c2e8904b6072d8eddab362ac50b324e374b5951d/fairseq/sequence_generator.py#L338):

```
lprobs[lprobs != lprobs] = torch.tensor(-math.inf).to(lprobs)
```

There is no comment, so is it some well-known Python (or PyTorch?) idiom? Could someone explain what it means, or show a different way that makes the intent clearer?

`lprobs` is a [pytorch `Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html), and it could contain any size float type (I doubt this code is intended to support int or complex types). As far as I know, the Tensor classes don't override the `__ne__` function.

Comment: It looks like `lprobs[lprobs != lprobs]` is selecting those elements of `lprobs` that contain NaN. Then it sets those to negative infinity...?

Comment: I'd guess a Tensor is based on e.g. a numpy matrix, this is the idiom: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm familiar with the `x[b]` idea. I'm confused by `x[x!=x]`.

Comment: This _is_ `x[b]`, where `b = x != x`. In the linked example the comparison (see also https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html?highlight=comparison#structure-comparison) that creates the mask is `y>20`.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what situation is an object not equal to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253497/in-what-situation-is-an-object-not-equal-to-itself)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a combination of [fancy indexing with a boolean mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), and a ["trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059796/1346276) (although intended by design) to check for `NaN`: `x != x` holds iff `x` is `NaN` (for floats, that is).

They could alternatively have written

```py
lprobs[torch.isnan(lprobs)] = torch.tensor(-math.inf).to(lprobs)
```

or, probably even more idiomatically, used [`torch.nan_to_num`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nan_to_num.html?highlight=nan#torch.nan_to_num) (but beware that the latter also has special behaviour towards infinities).

A non-updating variant of the above would be

```py
torch.where(torch.isnan(lprobs), torch.tensor(-math.inf), lprobs)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to using `is.nan` in R, and `isNaN()` in JavaScript, so naturally I like your alternative version much more! At first glance `torch.nan_to_num()` looks really nice and descriptive, but it also replaces -inf and +inf, which (IMHO) completely spoils the good idea (the function name is misleading rather than descriptive, and a possible efficiency concern too).

Comment: Uh, right. I only stumbled upon `nan_to_num` today and didn't realize it has that kind of behaviour.